# Get address of allocated memory by pointer to a base class for non-polymorphic types

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management

simple multi-inheritance

```
struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C : A, B {};
```

or virtual inheritance

```
struct B {};
struct C : virtual B {};
```

Please note types are not polymorphic.

Custom memory allocation:

```
template <typedef T, typename... Args>
T* custom_new(Args&& args...)
{
    void* ptr = custom_malloc(sizeof(T));
    return new(ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typedef T>
void custom_delete(T* obj)
{
    if (!obj)
        return obj;

    void* ptr = get_allocated_ptr(obj); // here
    assert(std::is_polymorphic_v<T> || ptr == obj);
    obj->~T();
    custom_free(ptr); // heap corruption if assert ^^ failed
}

B* b = custom_new<C>(); // b != address of allocated memory
custom_delete(b); // UB
```

How can I implement `get_allocated_ptr` for non polymorphic types? For polymorphic types `dynamic_cast<void*>` does the job.

Alternatively I could check that `obj` is a pointer to a base class as deleting a non polymorphic object by a pointer to base class is UB. I don't know how to do this or if it's possible at all.

`operator delete` properly deallocates memory in such cases (e.g. VC++), though standard says it's UB. How does it do this? compiler-specific feature?

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of this is, but on one hand you could use regex to find all the occurences of `~X()`. On the other hand, if this style is being praised (for performance, perhaps), please know that having a non-virtual destructor is very dangerous and could cause memory leaks if the derived types have additional variables.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: sorry that the question is not clear. We have custom global memory allocation with an ability to replace default allocator by user-provided. This means to delete an object we have to call it's destructor manually and then to free the memory (not necessarily by `free`). I don't need to look for `~X()` as it's called in a single place in my code. My problem is to free memory as I don't have a proper address, only a pointer to a (potentially) base class that is different than originally allocated memory

Comment: Are you saying `ptr != b` in your case?

Comment: @TonyJ: correct

Comment: @AndyT Ah, I see what you mean no with the none polymorphic case.

Comment: You need a run-time mechanism of type checking in some form. Polymorphic classes gives you such mechanism that is built in the code by the compiler. So the simplest way is to have some (possibly virtual) polymorphic base for classes you use with `custom_new`/`custom_delete`. Otherwise, you should implement such mechanism manually.

Comment: @Constructor: It's *global* memory allocation with user code that we don't control, otherwise we'd just implement base class with overwritten `new`/`delete` operators. "otherwise, you should implement such mechanism manually" - it's actually what I'm asking about - how to do this if it's possible at all

Comment: What about [such simple implementation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff3ba2620081b242)? Unfortunately, you need to fill the pointer to `this` instance of the class manually in all classes in a hierarchy you want to use. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28906b6f9db3569c) is an example for your second hierarchy.

Comment: @Constructor After some thought, I ended up with basically the same solution in my answer. However, in my implementation the pointer to `this` is set in the custom allocation.

Comment: I think you have a more serious problem than getting the address of the complete object.  In custom_delete, if T is actually a base class of the object passed in, then obj->~T() will only partially destroy the object.

Comment: @PeterRuderman No, you aren't correct. His code is ok, there is no problem with it. If `T` is a base class and doesn't have virtual destructor, then yes, there is a problem, but not in @AndyT's code. It's a basic c++ rule not to delete through base pointer if destructor isn't virtual.

Answer (score 5):

You actually have a more serious problem than getting the address of the full object.  Consider this example:

```
struct Base
{
  std::string a;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  std::string b;
};

Base* p = custom_new<Derived>();
custom_delete(p);
```

In this example, custom_delete will actually free the correct address (`static_cast<void*>(static_cast<Derived*>(p)) == static_cast<void*>(p)`), but the line `obj->~T()` will invoke the destructor for `Base`, meaning that the `b` field is leaked.

---

### So Don't Do That

Instead of returning a raw pointer from `custom_new`, return an object that is bound to the type T and that knows how to delete it.  For example:

```
template <class T> struct CustomDeleter
{
  void operator()(T* object) const
  {
    object->~T();
    custom_free(object); 
  }
};

template <typename T> using CustomPtr = std::unique_ptr<T, CustomDeleter<T>>;

template <typename T, typename... Args> CustomPtr<T> custom_new(Args&&... args)
{
  void* ptr = custom_malloc(sizeof(T));
  try
  {
    return CustomPtr<T>{ new(ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) };
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    custom_free(ptr);
    throw;
  }
}
```

Now it's impossible to accidentally free the wrong address and call the wrong destructor because the only code that calls custom_free knows the complete type of the thing that it's deleting.

*Note: Beware of the unique_ptr::reset(pointer) method.  This method is extremely dangerous when using a custom deleter since the onus is on the caller to supply a pointer that was allocated in the correct way.  The compiler can't help if the method is called with an invalid pointer.*

---

### Passing Around Base Pointers

It may be that you want to both pass a base pointer to a function *and* give that function responsibility for freeing the object.  In this case, you need to use *type erasure* to hide the type of the object from consumers while retaining knowledge of its most derived type internally.  The easiest way to do that is with a `std::shared_ptr`.  For example:

```
struct Base
{
  int a;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  int b;
};

CustomPtr<Derived> unique_derived = custom_new<Derived>();

std::shared_ptr<Base> shared_base = std::shared_ptr<Derived>{ std::move(unique_derived) };
```

Now you can freely pass around `shared_base` and when the final reference is released, the complete `Derived` object will be destroyed and its correct address passed to `custom_free`.  If you don't like the semantics of `shared_ptr`, it's fairly straightforward to create a type erasing pointer with `unique_ptr` semantics.

*Note: One downside to this approach is that the shared_ptr requires a separate allocation for its control block (which won't use `custom_malloc`).  With a little more work, you can get around that.  You'd need to create a custom allocator that wraps `custom_malloc` and `custom_free` and then use `std::allocate_shared` to create your objects.*

---

### Complete Working Example

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

void* custom_malloc(size_t size)
{
  void* mem = ::operator new(size);
  std::cout << "allocated object at " << mem << std::endl;
  return mem;
}

void custom_free(void* mem)
{
  std::cout << "freeing memory at " << mem << std::endl;
  ::operator delete(mem);
}

template <class T> struct CustomDeleter
{
  void operator()(T* object) const
  {
    object->~T();
    custom_free(object); 
  }
};

template <typename T> using CustomPtr = std::unique_ptr<T, CustomDeleter<T>>;

template <typename T, typename... Args> CustomPtr<T> custom_new(Args&&... args)
{
  void* ptr = custom_malloc(sizeof(T));
  try
  {      
    return CustomPtr<T>{ new(ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) };
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    custom_free(ptr);
    throw;
  }
}

struct Base
{
  int a;
  ~Base()
  {
    std::cout << "destroying Base" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  int b;
  ~Derived()
  {
    std::cout << "detroying Derived" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  // Since custom_new has returned a unique_ptr with a deleter bound to the
  // type Derived, we cannot accidentally free the wrong thing.
  CustomPtr<Derived> unique_derived = custom_new<Derived>();

  // If we want to get a pointer to the base class while retaining the ability
  // to correctly delete the object, we can use type erasure.  std::shared_ptr
  // will do the trick, but it's easy enough to write a similar class without
  // the sharing semantics.
  std::shared_ptr<Base> shared_base = std::shared_ptr<Derived>{ std::move(unique_derived) };

  // Notice that when we release the shared_base pointer, we destroy the complete
  // object.
  shared_base.reset();
}
```

Comment: What if you simply follow rule that if you delete from base pointer then destructor has to be virtual. This simple rule invalidates all your code. Minor point, `if (!mem) throw std::bad_alloc{};` - this simply doesn't happen in c++, `new` doesn't return NULL.

Comment: Good point about `operator new`.  I'll update my answer.  Virtual destructors certainly work, but they aren't free and they aren't always possible.  (You might have to manage types defined in someone else's code, for example.)  I also think that avoiding raw pointers is a good practice, regardless of whether you use virtual destructors or not.

Comment: Regarding new, you could just use non-throwing new: `::operator new(size, std::nothrow_t())`, but it's better not to, and keep consistent behavior in c++ so custom allocator also throws the same way.

Comment: Regarding virtual destructors: I guess they come with the price because otherwise it's possible to write code that will simply fail if it's not properly implemented. The idea with allocators is simple: it should just delete what you pass to it, it shouldn't have any weird requirements on top of normal allocators. If you try to delete by base pointer with no virtual destructor you should have a bug and shouldn't invent stuff to avoid that. That's IMO

Answer (score 1):

You can do that only using `dynamic_cast` and static type of `T` has to be polymorphic. Otherwise look at this code:

```
struct A { int a; };
struct B { int b; };
struct C : A, B {};

B *b1 = new C, *b2 = new B;
```

If you try to delete by pointer to B, there is no way to know if `b1` or `b2` needs to be adjusted to `get_allocated_ptr`. One way or another you need `B` to be polymorphic to get pointer to most derived object.

Answer (score 0):

What about a virtual interface that all structs inherit from, which returns the pointer at which the object was allocated? I had to make some changes to make the code compile. Both the multiple inheritance and virtual inheritance cases work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>

struct H {
public:
    void* getHeader() { return header; }
    void setHeader(void* ptr) { header = ptr; }
private:
    void* header;
};

// multiple inheritance case
//struct A : public virtual H { int a;};
//struct B : public virtual H { int b;};
//struct C : A, B { };

// virtual inheritance case
struct B : public virtual H { int b; };
struct C : virtual B {};

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
T* custom_new(Args&&... args) {
    void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(T));
    T* obj = new(ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    obj->setHeader(ptr);
    return obj;
}

template <typename T>
void* get_allocated_ptr(T* obj) {
    return obj->getHeader();
}

template <typename T>
void custom_delete(T* obj) {
    void* ptr = get_allocated_ptr(obj); // here
//  assert(std::is_polymorphic<T>::value || ptr == obj); // had to comment
    obj->~T();
    free(ptr); // heap corruption if assert ^^ failed
}

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    C* c = custom_new<C>(); // b != address of allocated memory
    std::cout << "PTR \t\t= " << c << std::endl;
    auto b = static_cast<B*>(c);
    std::cout << "CAST PTR \t= " << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ALLOCATED PTR \t= " << get_allocated_ptr(b) << std::endl; 
    custom_delete(b); // UB
}
```

You can run this with either hierarchy, and the output is something like

```
PTR             = 0x7f9fd4d00b90
CAST PTR        = 0x7f9fd4d00b98
ALLOCATED PTR   = 0x7f9fd4d00b90
```

although in the multiple inheritance case the pointers differ by 16 bits rather than 8 (because of the two integers).

This implementation could be improved by using templates to enable `custom_new` and the other functions only for structs inheriting from the `H` interface.

Comment: After finishing this, I realize it is essentially a struct-only equivalent of @Constructor 's suggestion